# Why my link button does a full post back although it 's triggered with an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, linkbutton

I have the following case :

a `link button` which triggered through `AsyncPostBackTrigger` .but still does a full post back !!

---

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnShowNotes" runat="server" CssClass="blue" OnClick="lbtnShowNotes_Click"> <img src="images/document_notes.png"/>notes</asp:LinkButton>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNotes" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_title" runat="server" Text="الملاحظات"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Coments" runat="server" Columns="70" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnOkNotes" runat="server"><img src="images/tick.png" alt=""/></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCancelNotes" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lbtnCancelNotes_Click"><img src="images/tick.png" alt=""/></asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnShowNotes" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

Comment: Have you tried to set `UpdateMode="Conditional"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `UpdatePanel`'s [`UpdateMode` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) to "Conditional".

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

The `UpdatePanel` is updated if the `UpdateMode` property is set to `Conditional`, and one of the following conditions occurs:

- You call the Update method of the UpdatePanel control explicitly.
- The postback is caused by a control that is **defined as a trigger by using the Triggers property** of the `UpdatePanel` control. In this scenario, the control explicitly triggers an update of the panel content. The control can be either inside **or outside the UpdatePanel** control that defines the trigger.
- ...

Comment: I find the cause to this problem :

`EnablePartialRendering ="false";` in the script manager , i set this property because some conflict between jquery and the update panel :(

Comment: JQuery and ASP.NET Ajax are enemies, unfortunately.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - jQuery is Web Development Friend and ASP.Net Ajax is Rapid Development Friend :)

Answer (score 6):

ClientIDMode Changes

The ClientIDMode setting in ASP.NET 4 lets you specify how ASP.NET generates the id attribute for HTML elements. In previous versions of ASP.NET, the default behavior was equivalent to the AutoID setting of ClientIDMode. However, the default setting is now Predictable.

If you use Visual Studio 2010 to upgrade your application from ASP.NET 2.0 or ASP.NET 3.5, the tool automatically adds a setting to the Web.config file that preserves the behavior of earlier versions of the .NET Framework. However, if you upgrade an application by changing the application pool in IIS to target the .NET Framework 4, ASP.NET uses the new mode by default. To disable the new client ID mode, add the following setting in the Web.config file:

```
<pages ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
```

or add ClientIDMode="AutoID" in your page directive.

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

[LinkButton in ListView in UpdatePanel causes full postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652728/linkbutton-in-listview-in-updatepanel-causes-full-postback)

Comment: Good find !! This fixed my issue since the application we were using started using Client id mode "Predictable" due to a version change to .NET 4.0. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Adding `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` in my page directive solved my problem.