# How to set gridview template field as target control for modal popup extender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way to set control (in template field of gridview) as target control for modal popup extender? I tried like here:

[Full postback triggered by LinkButton inside GridView inside UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872210/full-postback-triggered-by-linkbutton-inside-gridview-inside-updatepanel)

But I get an exception as value parameter can't be null. Please help in detail.

Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTemp" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TempNo" OnRowCommand="grdDULead_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdDULead_RowDataBound">
   <FooterStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="GridFooter" />
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="grDULeadlnkSelect" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" OnClick="grDULeadlnkSelect_Click" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="selectrow">select</asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Extender:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="grDULeadlnkSelect" PopupControlID="pnlCDAMTClar" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Code-behind:
At the start I got the error `could not find control "grDULeadlnkSelect"`. Then I tried to register button like so but I get the error `value cannot be null`.

```
protected void grdTemp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{     // getting err at below line.
     LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("grDULeadlnkSelect") as  LinkButton; 
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb); 
}
```

Comment: @Uneverno http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=212

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just set a dummy control ID as TargetControlID for the ModalPopUpExtender and make that dummy one invisible.

Now on RowCommand event of that GridView write:

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
```

Hope this will solve your problem.