# Error using ajax update panel control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I try to make a date picker using ImageButton and calender, to avoid screen flicker I used ajax update panel control, but some errors appear, it said "The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it."

Here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Calendar CssClass="form-control" ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a ScriptManager control and see if that works.The error is indicative enough to solve your problem.For details [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872210).

Comment: Okay I just figure it out, thanks